# width jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, width

Im trying to fix a website of some friends. I have implemented some jquery tabs, but I find no way to make the tabs full witdh within with the container, or at least, centered.
I have been more than 20 hours trying to fix this, but Im totally stuck. I think is a very simple  thing, but I dont really get it.

the site is tinyurl.com/ccs7blz, tabs are at the right side (detalle and so).

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some code will be a good starting point!

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal sample, and post it directly in the question.

Comment: I just placed a link to the especific site. Sorry, Im just new in here. If required, I can post the jquery file Im using for the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a really easy jQuery plugin that will do that for you.

http://sebnitu.github.com/HorizontalNav/

Just make sure it's linked properly to your site (as well as the jQuery library itself), then add

```
    $('.my-nav-selector').horizontalNav({});
```

to your custom js file (or in script tags in your html).

If there's more you want to do there's lots of options to customize it as well.

---

EDIT: **CSS Solution**

If you want a CSS only way, there might be something easier you could do.  It doesnt look like you have any modifiers on your `<li>` selector for your menu.  If you take the percent of the entire menu (100%), and divide it by the number of menu items (6), you can add that number as a percentage width to the ul li.

For instance, if I had

```
ul {
width:100%;
}
```

And I had 5 different menu items

```
<ul>
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
<li>Fourth</li>
<li>Fifth</li>
</ul>
```

Then I take the percentage of the menu width divided by the number of menu items:

100% / 5 menu items = 20%;

So I add:

```
ul li {
width:20%;

}
```

This should make the menu spread across the entire containing div.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that also before but it dident work. I will give a second chance.

Comment: I just did it again, but also dont work. I dont have that much knowledge of javascript, but I think Im doing something wrong. I have the script on my server, I linked in the head section then I open a script with that:    <script type="text/javascript" src='/javascript/idtags/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/idtags/jquery.horizontalNav.js"></script>
<script>
 $('.my-nav-selector').horizontalNav({});
</script>   But it doesnt work.

Comment: I edited my answer, try that new solution and it should work.  I tested in on your site in Firebug and it worked fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! The problem Im facing is not with the five elements side bar, just the three buttons on the right side (detalle, envios y devoluciones and Guia de Tallas). Thank you very much for your dedication.

Comment: I dont get it to work, but almost (Sorry, is getting non-stop 24 hours to fix this issue, Im mentally exhaust). There is three elements, If I apply 33% or 30% witdh, they separate, but there is a problem with the middle tab (Envíos y Devoluciones), I think is because is long text.

Comment: I guess .tabs li is where I have to put that percentage, but is not working. There is three styles. Style.css is for the right content with the three tabs. Tienda1.css is for the main shop, and also there is reset.css. I aplied width 100% within the html code in the tabs element (following one sugestion in here).

Comment: I think part of the problem is the way the tabs are set up.  Right now, the link (<a>) is inside the <li>, but the <a> is what's styled to look like a button so the child element ends up being larger than the parent.  Try switching those so that the <a> is surrounding the entire li, therefore making the entire li a link.  Either that, or instead of styling the <a>, style the <li>  Either of these should give you some more flexibility.

Comment: Let me try to fix it. Thanks for your dedication.

Comment: As you can see, Your sugestion have been of so many help. I was getting quite depressed and hopeless with this, but now I can see the light. The problem Im facing now is that the middle tab has a long text, so it breaks in two lines. Thanks very much!

Comment: No problem!  If it helped you would you mind accepting this as your answer so other people can see that it helped you?  Thanks!

Comment: Of course. You are awesome! Things are getting more clear now thanks to your help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can have the full width by editing the style.css line 59

```
.tabsContent {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I tried that before, but it doesnt work. Just did it now. This is driving me crazy.